# I want to add the tired condition here how is it possible

Tags: javascript

`<Card className={title === 'Income' ? classes.income :classes.expense}>`

I need to add a third condition here how is it possible?

Comment: Yes it is but for readability I would try to not do this via a ternary statement inline...

Answer (score 0):

You could put nested ternary statement.

For example

```
<Card className={title === 'Income' ? classes.income : title === 'Expense' ? classes.expense : classes.others }>
```

The ternary operator is right-associative, which means it can be "chained" in the following way, similar to an `if … else if … else if … else` chain:

```
function example(…) {
    return condition1 ? value1
         : condition2 ? value2
         : condition3 ? value3
         : value4;
}

// Equivalent to:

function example(…) {
    if (condition1) { return value1; }
    else if (condition2) { return value2; }
    else if (condition3) { return value3; }
    else { return value4; }
}
```